# I'm using Django to create an e-commerce website. While integrating payment into the project, I got a page not found (404) error

Tags: python, django, django-views

The error I got while I enter the customer detail and click on checkout:
[image]

This is my views.py of payment. Here I have imported stripe module using stripe api and created checkout session:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, reverse, get_object_or_404
from decimal import Decimal
import stripe
from django.conf import settings
from orders.models import Order

# Create your views here.

stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
stripe.api_version = settings.STRIPE_API_VERSION


def payment_process(request):
    order_id = request.session.get('order_id', None)
    order = get_object_or_404(Order, id=order_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        success_url = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('payment:completed'))
        cancel_url = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('payment:canceled'))

        session_data = {
            'mode': 'payment',
            'client_reference_id': order_id,
            'success_url': success_url,
            'cancel_url': cancel_url,
            'line_items': []
        }

        for item in order.items.all():
            session_data['line_items'].append({
                'price_data': {
                    'unit_amount': int(item.price * Decimal(100)),
                    'currency': 'usd',
                    'product_data': {
                        'name': item.product.name,
                    },
                },
                'quantity': item.quantity,
            })

        session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(**session_data)
        return redirect(session.url, code=303)

    else:
        return render(request, 'payment/process.html', locals())


def payment_completed(request):
    return render(request, 'payment/completed.html')


def payment_canceled(request):
    return render(request, 'payment/canceled.html')
```

This is urls.py of payment where I have created URL patterns for process where the order summary is displayed, stripe checkout session. completed for the successfull payment and canceled for payment cancelation. :

```
    from django.urls import path
    from . import views

    app_name = 'payment'


    urlpatterns = [
        path('canceled/', views.payment_canceled, name='canceled'),
        path('completed/', views.payment_completed, name='completed'),
        path('process/', views.payment_process, name='process'),
    ]
```

This is djangoProject urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('cart/', include('cart.urls', namespace='cart')),
    path('orders/', include('orders.urls', namespace='orders')),
    path('payment/', include('payment.urls', namespace='payment')),
    path('', include('ecommerce.urls', namespace='ecommerce')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: *No Order matches the given query.* - This is becouse you're using [`get_object_or_404(...)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) inside your view `get_object_or_404(Order, id=order_id)` check your `order_id` value

Comment: Need more explanation.

Comment: Hello @Bibek Rawat From doc: ***`get_object_or_404`** Calls **get()** on a given model manager, but it raises **Http404** instead of the model’s **DoesNotExist** exception.*  so if your `order_id` does not match or not exists in `Order` objects it will raise ***404***